# When should I edit an answer and when should I post a second answer?

Tags: discussion, editing, answers

I have posted an answer to this question:

[Assign a workflow task to the user who triggered the workflow rule](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/15716/498)

The original asker has now updated the question with more information, which will significantly change my answer.

I'm torn as to whether I should edit the answer I have already posted, which is (mostly) still valid, but I could change significantly, or whether I should just post a new answer which is significantly different from my original answer.

I'm leaning toward removing irrelevant information from my first answer and posting a brand new one.

Answer (score 3):

As much as I hate OP doing that - editing the question and changing it's nature 180 degree, instead of opening a new/updated question (in sake of keeping history in tact), If your "old" answer still answers the "new/updated" question, I don't see a problem making a 2nd/new answer.

If it does not meet the new question, feel free to delete/edit it.

Comment: By stating "...I hate OP doing that..." do you mean editing an existing question, or do you mean creating a second answer?

Comment: editing the question

Answer (score 2):

Since it's your own answer, I'd say edit away, or delete your old answer and post a new one.

When it comes to editing other people's answers, I try to be as conservative as possible and only correct spelling/grammar/formatting.